# SQLServer 2008 through odbc reports incorrect column string length

Tags: c++, sql-server-2008

I am building an app that uses ODBC to connect to MS SQL Server 2008. It detects automatically types of columns, their length (where applicable), allocates buffers for fetching and frees them when they're no longer needed. I need information about exact length of e.g. varchar column, so I am issuing a command that does just that - `SQLDescribeCol` for every column, just after `SQLExecute`.

**THE PROBLEM**

When issuing a query of:

`select 'F'`

I get a response from `SQLDescribeCol` that column has no name and it's length is 1. I allocate a buffer of 1+1 wchars and call `SQLFetch`, which returns `SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO`. Error state and text are `01004` and `String data, right truncated`, and after fetching no data is in the buffer. Right before fetching i use `SQLBindCol`, where the last parameter is a pointer to an integer, that holds length of the string after it was fetched. It's value is 2. When i change 'F' to be 'FFF', resulting string length expands to 6. Five character text results in size of 10. This means **twice the characters** I wrote.

This doesn't happen with long buffers fetched directly from the column. ColLength + one wchar (for null terminator) is enough.

**RAMBLINGS**

Does this have anything to do with character witdh? I am issuing queries that are all written in wchars, database collation is POLISH_CI_AS (I don't know whether MSSQL has some other property than collation, e.g. character width or anything along those lines). Although **when I change allocator function to allocate twice as much wchars as needed, I get proper data** (I mean I get that little 'F', and ony that 'F', where it's supposed to be).

Please advise. Is there anything I can do to avoid allocating twice as much memory as I need?

**EDIT** - code sample

```
short resultavail=0;
SQLHSTMT hstmt = NULL;
cResultColMetaData rcm; //class defined elsewhere, holds info about a column
//handle allocations, and all that's required to connect is not included
SQLRETURN retcode = SQLPrepare(hstmt, L"SELECT 'F'", SQL_NTS); //success
retcode = SQLNumParams (hstmt, &numParams); //success, no parameters
retcode = SQLExecute(hstmt); //success
retcode = SQLNumResultCols(hstmt, &resultavail); //success, resultavail holds "1"
wchar_t CName[200]; CName[0]=(wchar_t)0;
SQLSMALLINT howmuch=0;
retcode = SQLDescribeCol(hstmt, i+1, CName, 200, &howmuch, &rcm.type, &rcm.colsize, &rcm.decdigits, &rcm.nullable);
//success, at this point rcm.type is varchar and rcm.colsize is 1. I allocate a buffer
switch(rcm.type){
  //(...)
  case SQL_VARCHAR:
    {
       int sizev = rcm.colsize+1;
       wchar_t *str = new wchar_t[sizev];
       SQLINTEGER x = 0; //initialized to zero
       retcode = SQLBindCol(hstmt, 1, SQL_C_WCHAR, str, sizev, &x); //success
    }
}

retcode = SQLFetch(hstmt); //result = SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO,
//variable x now holds 2, no data in str buffer.
```

I hope this example somehow depicted my situation. This is ripped off of a class I wrote for this purpose, so some (de-) allocations or initializations may not be visible here. All in all, I'm facing a discrepancy between what `SQLDescribeCol` returns as column size and what `SQLFetch` returns in `x` variable.

Please help me identify the cause.

Answer (score 1):

I re-read MSDN documentation on `SQLBindCol` and I found out the reason. I'm using wchars, so the length of the buffer reported by me to function `SQLBindCol` should be **multiplied by sizeof(wchar_t)**, because this parameter is in **BYTES**, not in characters.

Earlier, I wrote that *This doesn't happen with long buffers fetched directly from the column*. This statement is incorrect. Problem just didn't HAPPEN to manifest. When `SQLDescribeCol` returned MAX column size, not it's ACTUAL data character length, which at this point isn't even known (before fetching). So I was allocating enough of a buffer all along, just reporting half of it to `SQLBindCol`. If I was retrieving other string data longer than half of MAX column size, I would stumble upon this problem earlier and probably wouldn't waste as much time as I did to debug it.